# How to manage compiling errors in VBA

Tags: excel, error-handling, compiler-errors, vba

I have an excel macro and this variable declared inside a Sub():

```
Dim ACAD As AcadApplication
```

And if the computer does not have AutoCAD, I obtain a compiling error. Then, what I want to do is to manage this error in order to show a message to the user like:

```
MsgBox "You have to install AutoCAD 2013 or later", vbCritical, "APPLICATION ERROR"
```

I have googled for a long time with no answer. Maybe I didn't use correctly key words.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What error trapping do you have in your code at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use create object instead of adding reference and declaring it using dim
Below is and example

```
    On Error Goto AppNotfound 
    Set Web = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    On Error Goto 0
    'Your Code here
    Exit Sub
    AppNotfound:
Msgbox("You have to install AutoCAD 2013 or later")

Exit Sub
End Sub
```